# make node.js not exit after ssh2 connection error

Tags: node.js

I have the following code in my node.js app to test the SSH connection to a server using ssh2 :

```
    var Connection   = require('ssh2');
    var conn         = new Connection();
    conn.on('ready', function() {
        console.log('Connection :: ready');
        conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
            if (err) throw err;
            stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
              console.log('Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
            }).on('close', function() {
              console.log('Stream :: close');
              conn.end();
            }).on('data', function(data) {
              console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
              console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
            });
        });
    }).connect({
      host: serverIp,
      port: serverPort,
      username: serverUsername,
      privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('./id_rsa')
    });
```

It works fine, but if it returns an error, if I get a connection timeout for example, the node.js app crashes...

I would like to do the following :

- if an error is returned, simply redirect to /servers page without crashing the app.

I tried to change the "if (err) throw err;" line with "if (err) res.redirect('/servers');" but it doesn't work...

Can someone help me with this noobie question ? I'm new to node.js :)

thanks a lot.

Comment: You probably don't have access to the `res` object. You need to put the whole `conn.on('ready',..` inside your route handler.

Comment: It is inside my route handler, and I do have access to the `res` object but thanks for your message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listen to the `error` event:

```
conn.on('error', function(e) { /* do whatever */ });
```

Right now, your process crashes b/c that connection error is unhandled.